# Rails jsonb columns in graphql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I am trying to set up types for my 'A' model that uses store_accessor. I am not sure how to define the column that has the JSON column - :foo

```
class   A < ActiveRecord 
   store_accessor :foo, :bar, :baz
end

Types::AType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
   name ‘A’

  field:  id, !types.ID
  field :bar, !types.String, hash_key: :bar
  field :baz, !types.String, hash_key: :baz
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom ScalarType called **JSONType**

```
JSONType = GraphQL::ScalarType.define do
  name "JSON Type"
  coerce_input -> (value) { JSON.parse(value) }
  coerce_result -> (value) { value }
end
```

And consume it in ObjectType definition

```
field :foo, JSONType do
    resolve Resolvers::Foo.new
end
```